# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to read data from firebase database. My app crashes when I run it and I seem to be getting this isChangingConfigurations error. Note that this Info class is a Fragment and I do not want to read the database using a listview. How do I solve this issue?

[Reading data from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vTJN.jpg)

```
public class Info extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String userID;

    private TextView resNameChange, statusChange;

    public Info() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();

        resNameChange = rootView.findViewById(R.id.resNameChange);
        statusChange = rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusChange);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            RestaurantInformation resInfo = new RestaurantInformation();
            resInfo.setResName(ds.child(userID).getValue(RestaurantInformation.class).getResName()); // error in this line ************
            resInfo.setStatus(ds.child(userID).getValue(RestaurantInformation.class).getStatus());

            resNameChange.setText(resInfo.getResName());
            statusChange.setText(resInfo.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

The RestaurantInformation class

```
public class RestaurantInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String resName;
    private String status;

    public RestaurantInformation() {

    }

        public RestaurantInformation(String resName, String status) {
        this.resName = resName;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getResName() {
        return resName;
    }

    public void setResName(String resName) {
        this.resName = resName;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message: `isChangingConfigurations` is the name of a method of `Activity`. Firebase can't serialize the Activity object. You should remove this part:

```
 extends AppCompatActivity
```

And don't forget to remove import `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem 
I had a class which was declared in the Acivity so i changed the declaration for the class from the acivity to the package level and the error is gone

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Removing AppCompatActivity, it will not work some parts of the code, for example,
findViewById.